# Selection sort coming up with an error exception in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, selection-sort

I am a bit stuck doing example of selection sort, so i am using the below logic and comparing each element of left side and moving to right side if it is higher.

I am not sure if i am missing anything with this logic.

I would appreciate if someone can guide any approach when debugging the issues like this?

Note: I am currently using Eclipse

/**
*
*/
package com.datastructureandalgo.all;

```
/**
 * @author Umair
 * 
 */
public class selectionSort {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arrayInt = { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 };

        for (int lastUnsortedIndex = arrayInt.length - 1; lastUnsortedIndex > 0; lastUnsortedIndex--) {

          

            int tempHighIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= lastUnsortedIndex; i++) {               // line 26

                if (arrayInt[tempHighIndex] > arrayInt[i + 1]) {
                    tempHighIndex = i;
                 } else {
                    tempHighIndex = i + 1;
             }

            replace(arrayInt, tempHighIndex, lastUnsortedIndex);

        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<arrayInt.length;i++) {
            
            System.out.println(arrayInt[i]);
            
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @param arrayInt
     * @param tempHighIndex
     * @param lastUnsortedArray
     */
    private static void replace(int[] arrayInt, int tempHighIndex, int lastUnsortedArray) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        arrayInt[lastUnsortedArray] = arrayInt[tempHighIndex];
    }

}
```

-`Error in Console`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 7 out of bounds for length 7    at
> com.datastructureandalgo.all.selectionSort.main(selectionSort.java:26)

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: The error is clear. Java arrays are 0-based.

Comment: As the Exception says. You try to access an index of the array that is higher than the size of the array. So the next step is to debug how it could happen that the index reaches an invalid value.